# Powershell functions not recognized when calling from command line

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple problem.  My powershell script contains a couple of functions and the script calls these functions no problem.

However, when I try to run powershell from the command line to execute my script, I get the error;

```
The term 'MyFunction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....'
```

Everywhere tells me I need to run my script like so from the command line for it to work;

```
powershell "& "'C:\My Path\script.ps1'"
```

This runs the script but the functions still do not work.  I get the errors wherever my script calls one of the functions.  What am I doing wrong?  I have even gone as far as creating another script with a single line in it that just says;

```
. C:\My Path\script.ps1
```

This again works fine but then when run through the command line it fails with the same errors.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
The function is defined like this;

```
function MyFunction ($id1, $id2) {
    ....
}
```

And it is called like this;

```
MyFunction $var1 $var2
```

The following script file resolved my issue and can be run from the command line fine;

```
Import-Module 'C:\My Path\script.ps1'
MyStartFunction  # calls other functions

powershell "& "'C:\My Path\AboveScriptFile.ps1'"
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the script with MyFunction definition?

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect this

Comment: And do you want to call the function from the command line after executing the script or from within the script?

Comment: From within the script.  I have added the below answer to the top of my script that runs . C:\My Path\script.ps1 and it has worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Import-Module` cmdlet in powershell session(window):

```powershell
Import-Module 'C:\My Path\script.ps1'
```

then you can run `MyFunction $var1 $var2` for the duration of that session.

If you want your script to execute a function contained within it, then add the following line to the bottom. It assumes you are passing two arguments in when executing the script( ie. `powershell 'C:\My Path\script.ps1' "value1" "value2"`)

```powershell
MyFunction $args[0] $args[1]
```

Comment: I added this to my short script that runs the main script and this works.  Thank you!

Comment: Note that if you are using Import-Module from a prompt to use MyFunction there, and want to change the function, you need to use `Remove-Module script ` where 'script' is module name / file name